# Excel VBA Range.Rows iterator order of rows processed

Tags: vba, excel

I need to traverse a range from the bottom of the spreadsheet to the top of the spreadsheet.  The range can be discontinuous, but I have removed overlaps (I'm only concerned with the row order, so I've also reduced the column to "A") and placed the range in "Overall_Range".  Since the areas can come into the range in any order, I've built a function, Get_Loop_Order, that returns an array with order in which the areas should be processed to go from bottom to top.  My plan was to just iterate over each area (from bottom to top) like this:

```
Loop_Order = Get_Loop_Order(Overall_Range)
For A = LBound(Loop_Order) To UBound(Loop_Order)
  For Each this_row In Overall_Range.Areas(Loop_Order(A)).Rows
    ... do stuff ...
  Next this_row
Next A
```

I realized that the For Each on Range.Rows will not be processed in reverse order (in fact, I have no guarantee of the order at all as far as I know).

Does anyone know if there is a way to loop through a range that is guaranteed to occur in a specific row order?  When I select (the use of the word "select" here should not be confused with the Excel VBA term "Selection," the code above uses "Overall_Range") a range from bottom to top (A10:A2) the loop is in that order, when I select a range from top to bottom (A2:A10) it is in that order.  I have no idea what happens if I do something like Union(A10:A2, A1:A2).  I'm thinking that I will have to write another function that returns an array with the order to process things, but I'd love it if someone else had another solution.  Can you help?

UPDATE:

I did some more testing Here is the code:

```
Dim my_range As Range 'Range being tested
Dim N As Long         'Loop variable when numbers are needed
Dim M As Range        'Loop variable when ranges are needed

Set my_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10")

ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "A2:A10"
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:C1").Merge
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = "Row Index"
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = "Row Iterator"
ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("C2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

For N = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & N + 2).Value = my_range.Rows(N).Row
Next N

N = 1
For Each M In my_range.Rows
    ActiveSheet.Range("C" & N + 2).Value = M.Row
    N = N + 1
Next M

Set my_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A2")

ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = "A10:A2"
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E1").Merge
ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value = "Row Index"
ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("D2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value = "Row Iterator"
ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("E2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

For N = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & N + 2).Value = my_range.Rows(N).Row
Next N

N = 1
For Each M In my_range.Rows
    ActiveSheet.Range("E" & N + 2).Value = M.Row
    N = N + 1
Next M

Set my_range = Union(ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2"))

ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value = "UNION(A10:A2,A1:A2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("F1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("F1:G1").Merge
ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Value = "Row Index"
ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("F2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value = "Row Iterator"
ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("G2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

For N = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("F" & N + 2).Value = my_range.Rows(N).Row
Next N

N = 1
For Each M In my_range.Rows
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & N + 2).Value = M.Row
    N = N + 1
Next M

Set my_range = Union(ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("A11:A12"))

ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Value = "UNION(A10:A2,A13:A15,A11:A12)"
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("H1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("H1:I1").Merge
ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value = "Row Index"
ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("H2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Value = "Row Iterator"
ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("I2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

For N = 1 To my_range.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Range("H" & N + 2).Value = my_range.Rows(N).Row
Next N

N = 1
For Each M In my_range.Rows
    ActiveSheet.Range("I" & N + 2).Value = M.Row
    N = N + 1
Next M
```

The results are something that I cannot post because I cannot post images...sigh...they show that no matter how crazy the range is, when accessed via the Rows collection, they come in row order.

This seems to show that the rows are consistently returned in order no matter what crazy thing I do with the range if I access it via the Rows collection.  I'm thinking that this means the approach of just stepping backwards through the range (as suggested in the comments) will work.

Comment: Why do you have to use `For Each` rather than a "For n = Range.Rows.Count to 1 step -1` for example?

Comment: Perhaps you can check not only the selected row (which would be `2` when `A2:A10` is selected, or the top row in any selection you make - whether selected from top or bottom first), but also the activecell row (which would be the row for the first row selected). Not a real answer, but perhaps some directional help.

Comment: @Rory: That is a great suggestion, and could be used after determining whether the selection started at the top or bottom.

Comment: The top-left cell of any selection is always the `ActiveCell`.  So, whether you select A1:10, or A10:A1, `Selection.Address = $A$1:$A$10`, and `ActiveCell` will be `$A$1`.

Comment: Loop through a range in desired order/step using the method @Rory describes, you need indexed iteration, not a simple for/each.

Comment: @DavidZemens Not necessarily - *any* cell in a selection could be active.

Comment: @DavidZemens Again, not necessarily. I frequently have occasion to select right to left, or bottom to top. ;)

Comment: But it still doesn't re-order the Address, so while you could maybe use the active cell as a reasonable proxy for determining the "order" of the selection, it's not 100% reliable as such.

Comment: @Rory, the For loop you suggested only works if the range goes from A1:A10 and not A10:A1.

Comment: @guitarthrower the activecell may not be in the area that I am processing.

Comment: @bfish: your question states that you want to loop based on a selection that you make. I assumed that you would be using that selection in your code. If that is the case, then the active cell would be in the area you are processing. If not, then you should update your question with how you are passing the range to the code.

Comment: @guitarthrower I'm sorry it wasn't clear.  I tried everywhere to use the word "range" instead of selection.  I showed in the code sample that I use "Overall_Range" to pass in the range.  The range can be discontinuous (so it could have several areas).  I'm happy to edit the question, but the word "selection" does not appear.  I'm sorry, again, if my question was confusing.  I added a parenthetical after the word "select" in the above question to try and make it clearer.  Hope that helped.

Comment: @Rory if you add your first suggestion as an answer, I will check it...

Comment: @BFISH. thanks for the clarification. From a VBA perspective Range("A2:A10") and Range("A10:A2") are exactly the same (i.e. they return the same address: $A$2:$A$10). In order to loop one way or another, you'll need to pass another argument. My solution with some modification will work with your needs as well. I'll edit with some modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do the trick.

With one clarification: From a VBA perspective `Range("A2:A10")` and `Range("A10:A2")` are exactly the same (i.e. they return the same address: `$A$2:$A$10`). In order to loop one way or another, you'll need to pass another argument.

EDIT

It takes the `Overall_Range` that you provide, then the direction of `Up` or `Down` then assigns values to variables to use in the `For` statement.

No selections used.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopOrderTest()
    Dim Overall_Range As Range
    Dim sLoopDir As String
    Dim iTtlRows As Integer
    Dim iLoopStep As Integer
    Dim iLoopFrom As Integer
    Dim iLoopTo As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    Set Overall_Range = Range("A2:A10")
    sLoopDir = "Up" 'or "Down"

    iTtlRows = Overall_Range.Rows.Count 'Get total rows

    'Assign for loop control items based on sLoopDir value
    If sLoopDir = "Up" Then
        iLoopFrom = 1
        iLoopTo = iTtlRows
        iLoopStep = 1
    ElseIf sLoopDir = "Down" Then
        iLoopFrom = iTtlRows
        iLoopTo = 1
        iLoopStep = -1
    End If

    Dim i As Integer 'used only to put items in cells for testing
    i = 1

    For n = iLoopFrom To iLoopTo Step iLoopStep
        'do stuff.
        'for now just print a number showing the order that the loop works through
        Overall_Range.Cells(n, 1).Value = i
        i = i + 1
    Next n
End Sub
```

This shows what happens when I set `sLoopDir = "Up"` and run the code. Numbers ascending indicate it loops from top to bottom.

[image: top to bottom]

This shows what happens when I set `sLoopDir = "Down"` and run the code. Numbers descending indicate it loops from bottom to top.

[image: bottom to top]

Comment: I think that your solution works without consideration for the ActiveCell at all.  I consistently need to process the range in reverse order.  The insight, however, that "A2:A10" returns the exact same range as "A10:A2" (e.g. $A$2:$A$10) was what I really needed, so your answer gets the check.

Comment: Excellent. Your question was asking for both directions, hence my response. Glad this worked for you.